# Precision equal to scale in MS SQL-Server

Tags: sql-server

I recently came across a column declaration where the precision equal to scale :

```
...
[MYCOLUMN] [decimal](5, 5) NULL,
...
```

According to this [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) this seems correct.

But i don't understand, does it means that the decimal intended to fit in, can only have numbers to the right of the decimal point ?

Comment: decimal(5,3) means the length of value is 5 means `12.345` and 3 means you can use 3 number after decimal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it means that only decimals are allowed when inserting into the table. Everything else will be truncated and will most likely generate a "Data will be truncated" warning.

So the possible values for that column are in the following range:

`0 - 0.99999`

Have a look at this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fc971/1). If you uncomment the inserting of `1` into the table you will get a truncation error.

Also, in case SQLFiddle ever goes down, here is the code:

```
create table test (col1 decimal(5,5));

insert into test values (0.12345);
insert into test values (0);
-- insert into test values (1);

select *
from test
```

Comment: you will most likely get an `Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric` error trying to insert anything greater than zero. Try it out: `declare @Test table (MYCOLUMN decimal(5, 5) NULL);insert into @test values (1.1);select * from @test`

Comment: @KM Yes, that sounds more plausible. I don't have access to a SQL Server DB right now, so I can't check and say exactly the message you'd get.

Comment: Your `-- insert into test values (1);` will fail. Not truncation error but arithetic overflow.